# Can You Whitelist Domains in ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using a ZeroMQ server and client model to communicate between 2 hosts over LAN. I was looking at security and think a strawhouse pattern will suffice for this. I'm simply looking to whitelist the client from the server.

The thing is, the client is usually a raspberry pi. Is it possible to use the "raspberrypi.local" domain for the whitelist? I haven't found anything that really answers this question.

For some context, I'm implementing a library that will allow sharing of python objects via pickling and syncing using ZeroMQ.

Comment: Are you using pyzmq?

Comment: Yes. I figured out a workaround. I can just use python sockets to get the hostname of a domain a person enters.